# ImageView in Actionbar not displayed correctly in some devices

Tags: android, android-actionbar, imageview

I am using the below code to center an ImageView in ActionBar in Android. I tested this on a couple of devices and while it works properly on some, it doesnt work in others. I am attaching screenshots taken from different devices along

```
private void setupActionBar() {
    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    ab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_add_person);

    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.action_bar_head, null);
    ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
    ab.setCustomView(v, layoutParams);
}
```

and the XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_logo" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Working properly on Xiaomi Redmi 1s
[image: Working properly]
Not working on Moto E
[image: Not working]

Comment: instead of android:layout_centerInParent="true" use  android:layout_centerInHorizontal="true" in xml file

Comment: Change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Comment: are you using 9 patch image if not please try with 9 patch drawable image